# Adding the value that most appears in each row of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
> head (PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  2  2  2  1  1
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  3  4  0  0
5  5  5  1  2  0
6  0  0  0  1  1
```

I would like to add column to the dataframe that will contain the number the appears most times in each row. As followed:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 max_res
1  0  0  0  0  0    0
2  2  2  2  1  1    2
3  0  0  0  0  0    0
4  0  3  4  0  0    0
5  5  5  1  2  0    5
6  0  0  1  1  1    1
```

I use the following code:

```
g <- function(df)
{
  X <- as.data.frame(t(apply( df, 1,
                              function(row)
                              {
                                u <- unique(row)
                                n <- rowSums(outer(u,row,"=="))
                                if (length(u)==1 )
                                {
                                  c(row,u[which.max(n)],max(n),"",0)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                  c(row,u[which.max(n)],max(n))
                                }
                              })))  

  colnames(X) <- c(colnames(df),"max_res")

  return(X)
}

g1<-g(PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2)
```

When I try to 
`>head (g1)` 
I get very weird results such as:

```
  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
                        NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
                        NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
                   NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
                   NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                       NA
                   NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                       NA
                   NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                       NA
                   NA                  NA                  NA                       NA                  NA
```

The `PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2` dataframe details are:

```
 > str (PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2)
'data.frame':   100000 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ V3: Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ V4: Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ V5: Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Cath! Is there a way to convert all the dataframe into numeric dataframe?

Comment: The dataframe is very big....

Comment: This is how it is created:
PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2 = matrix(0, nrow(testing2), 5)
PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2<-as.data.frame (PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2)

for (i in 1:(5)) {
  PRED_BEST_SYSM_TEST2[,i]<- (predict(cart.models[BEST_SYSM_TREES_TRAIN[[i]]], testing2[,c(1:10)],type='class'))}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158694/discussion-between-avi-and-cath).

Comment: @Cath! This is not duplicate! the list of Q&A are for maximal values! My is for maximal number of occurrence!

Comment: Sorry, your title was misleading, I changed the target